# Error 10053 connecting with Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2005

While I try to connect to SQL Server, I am getting the following error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10053)

How can this be solved? What may be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Can you connect at all? Even locally on the server? ANd what does the Windows event log say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several causes for this. The ones I know of (at least)

- [max server memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx) set to 0
- [user connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187030.aspx) set to 1 (limiting you to one only)
- and possibly server side SSL enabled

Have you ever connected? Changed any settings? Have a backup of master? What other errors are there in the event log?

Anyhow, restart SQL Server with the [-f option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190737.aspx) and ensure the the 2 settings above are sensible.

Comment: Your reply is almost correct. Restarted that particular instance and I could now connect to the same..Thanks for that..
:)